# CMAKE - setting compile flags for libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries, flags

I have a CMakeLists.txt script to compile my libraries. 
The problem is I cannot set the compile flags for the libraries.

I've tried

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/W3 /nologo /EHsc")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd /Od /Ob0 /Zi /RTC1 /DDEBUG /D_DEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "/W3 /nologo /EHsc")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd /Od /Ob0 /Zi /RTC1 /DDEBUG /D_DEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "/W3 /nologo /EHsc")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd /Od /Ob0 /Zi /RTC1 /DDEBUG /D_DEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "/W3 /nologo /EHsc")
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd /Od /Ob0 /Zi /RTC1 /DDEBUG /D_DEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "/W3 /nologo /EHsc")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd /Od /Ob0 /Zi /RTC1 /DDEBUG /D_DEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS "/W3 /nologo /EHsc")
SET(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd /Od /Ob0 /Zi /RTC1 /DDEBUG /D_DEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG")
```

None of those have effect...

The only way I can change flags for a library is like this.

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(MyLib PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/W3 /nologo /EHsc")
```

and this will change the flags for both Debug and Release

How in the world can I set the Release and Debug flags separately for a library using CMake?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those are globally cached variables you are trying overwrite in your first approach.

Changing those compiler/linker options locally you need config-specific target properties or [generator expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html). So taking your second approach and [How can I set specific compiler flags for a specific target in a specific build configuration using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199904/how-can-i-set-specific-compiler-flags-for-for-a-specific-target-in-a-specific-bu) I would get:

```
target_compile_options(
    MyLib PRIVATE 
    /W3 /nologo /EHsc
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/MTd;/Od;/Ob0;/Zi;/RTC1;/DDEBUG;/D_DEBUG>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/MT;/O2;/Ob2;/DNDEBUG>"
)
```

or for CMake versions <= 2.8.12 (see also [policy CMP0043](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/policy/CMP0043.html)):

```
set_target_properties(
    MyLib PROPERTIES 
        COMPILE_FLAGS 
            "/W4 /nologo /EHsc"
        COMPILE_FLAGS_DEBUG
            "/MTd /Od /Ob0 /Zi /RTC1"
        COMPILE_FLAGS_RELEASE
            "/MT /O2 /Ob2"
        COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG
            "DEBUG;_DEBUG"
        COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE
            "NDEBUG"
)
```

I personally like the "OLD" way of doing it better, because it replaces the default options in Visual Studio's project properties. Whatever is passed via `target_compile_options()` will end up in `Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Command Line / Additional Options`.

**Some background information why your first approach didn't work:**

CMake's generator takes whatever is set for `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` at the end of any `CMakeLists.txt` file and applies it to all library and executable targets in the same `CMakeLists.txt` file as the default compiler options when generating the build environment.

If you set the linker variables for you main `CMakeLists.txt` targets in subdirectories `CMakeLists.txt` it won't help (wrong scope). If I take your above code into the main `CMakeLists.txt` it does work and I get the following warnings (because you used compiler options for the linker):

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/W3'; ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/EHsc'; ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/MTd'; ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/Od'; ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/Ob0'; ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/Zi'; ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/RTC1'; ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/DDEBUG'; ignored
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/D_DEBUG'; ignored
```

I'm now hiding the cached variables of the same name set by CMake during the compiler detection. For more details see:

- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)
- [CMake: In which order are files parsed (cache, toolchain, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks for the references.  I believe target_compile_options with generators are supported in [2.8.12](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_compile_options).

Comment: I had to remove the quotation marks from the generator example to get this working with GCC 9.2.