# cmake - Global linker flag setting (for all targets in directory)

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

I want to pass linker flags to all sub-projects (sub-directory CMakeList) in my project.

Before switching to new cmake 3.3, I was using the following code (cmake 3.2) which was working well, adding flags for both compilation and linking :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -stdlibc++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -stdlibc++")
```

With cmake 3.3 this no longer works and set the flags only for compilation step. I updated the CMakeList to use a more "modern" cmake syntax :

```
set(MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS -g -stdlib=libstdc++ -Wfatal-errors)
set(MY_RELEASE_OPTIONS -O3 -stdlib=libstdc++ -Wfatal-errors)

add_compile_options(
  "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>"
  "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${MY_RELEASE_OPTIONS}>")
```

This set compilation flags for all sub-projects, is there a similar way of doing this for linker flags ? I know one can add linker flags on a target basis with `target_link_libraries`command but can't find anything else.

I tried using `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` (and corresponding var for exe, module,..) variable with no success.

**Update :**

It turns out that this has nothing to do with cmake version, things work correctly with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_XXX`variables, except on first make command. If one run `make` a second time (with a modification in CmakeList), flags are presents.

I think I found a solution while testing with a simple CMakeList : if flags are declared after the `project` command it just work as expected. I don't know if it's a requirement from cmake itself or just a weird behavior.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2)

set(PROJECT Test_Project)

# Not working (on first run)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -stdlib=libstdc++ -Wfatal-errors")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g -stdlib=libstdc++ -Wfatal-errors")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O3 -stdlib=libstdc++ -Wfatal-errors")

project(${PROJECT})

# Declare here instead...

add_executable(Test test.cpp)

MESSAGE( STATUS "Config flags : " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})
```

Using :

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
```

Comment: I was wondering why your first approach should have stopped working with `CMake` 3.3. So I checked the changes to the code like `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` and `CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY` in [`CMakeCXXInformation.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blame/master/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake). But there is nothing obvious, so could you please add some details on your targeted make environment? It looks like `GNU`, but what version/flavor/OS do you use?

Comment: You are right, I was wrong, the problem is here with cmake 3.2 too. I made a very simple "Hello world" project and the problem is : first time I run `make` after `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .`, no flags are present apart from cmake default flags (eg. -O3, -DNDEBUG for release build). Then if I update CMakeList file (eg. add a space in flags string), cmake now add all flags correctly. (on os x yosemite with xcode toolchain)

Comment: Ok, then it's the same issue as with [CMake cross-compiling: C flags from toolchain file ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423313/cmake-cross-compiling-c-flags-from-toolchain-file-ignored). See [my answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423313/cmake-cross-compiling-c-flags-from-toolchain-file-ignored/30217088#30217088) for some background information. In short, just put your variable `set()` commands after the `project()` command.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. Thanks for the background info !

Comment: You're welcome. I've added an answer to cover the findings, sample code and background information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problems are/were not related to a specific CMake version.

It's the same for all linker/compiler flag variables in CMake. Because those variables are cached variables and set with the `project()`/`enable_language()` command (details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)), you either have to

1. prefill the cache with `set(... CACHE ...)` before the `project()` command
2. generally use the `set(... CACHE ... FORCE)` to force/overwrite
3. move the `set()` after the `project()` command to hide or append to the cached variables

Here is an example for `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` showing all three variants:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# 1. prefill
#set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-Map=output.map" CACHE INTERNAL "")

project(Test_Project CXX)

# 2. force
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-Map=output.map" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)

# 3. hide
#set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-Map=output.map")
# 3. or append
#set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Map=output.map")

# TODO: Remove, this is just for testing
file(WRITE "foo.cpp" "int main() {}") 

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} foo.cpp)
```

Whatever the values of those variables are at the end of your any given `CMakeLists.txt` file will be applied to all corresponding targets in the same `CMakeLists.txt` file as defaults (see [CMAKE - setting compile flags for libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621092/cmake-setting-compile-flags-for-libraries) and [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)).

The first variant has the disadvantage that it's really only the initial value. The second and third variant would most likely need an `if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)` around it, so I prefer the second variant with moving those settings to its own initial-cache file:

**MyGNUSettings.cmake**

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libstdc++ -Wfatal-errors" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-Map=output.map" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
```

Using e.g.

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -C MyGNUSettings.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  .
```

And yes - for the global and per compiler settings - I prefer the global cached variables over the `add_compile_options()` command. I think `add_compile_options()` haven't replaced the global variables, it was mainly introduced to prevent people putting compiler options in [`add_definitions()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_definitions.html) commands.

Comment: Thanks, very good explanation, I updated my CMakeList to take this into account. Not sure if I should update the question title.

Comment: Maybe just remove the "CMake 3.3" part from the title?

Comment: I don't think toolchain files should be (ab)used for setting such flags which should probably go into some CMakeLists.txt file. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html where the purpose of toolchain files is only described for cross compilation scenarios, setting things like `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`, `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` etc.

Comment: @letmaik Toolchain files are not only used in cross-compilation scenarios. It can add support for all compiler toolchains not directly supported/identified by CMake. Cross-compilation is defined by adding [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.html). But you are right, I updated my answer to recommend initial-cache files instead of toolchain files in this scenario.