# Is Cmake set variable recursive?

Tags: recursion, cmake

I am trying to modify compiler flags for all the directories below a certain directory (i.e. for all the current directories subdirectories and all their subdirectories recursively). So I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13639476/52074) there is two ways:

```
add_directory(dir1)
# ...
add_directory(dirN)

add_compile_options(flag1 flag2 ...)
# or for CMake versions < 3.0 to do something more like:
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} flag1 flag2 ...")
```

The man page for `add_compile_options` is very clear in stating that the effect will be "current directory and below" (which is what I want) but for `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)` I am not so sure.

**Is Cmake set variable recursive?**

Comment: What do you mean by recursive? The variable will be define in the same scope after `set(..)`. So if you define it not inside a macro or function and your add_subdirectores call come after the set(..), the variable is defined in the subdirectories, too.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith I grazed this topic again several times over the last months and have done some additional testing to see how the compile flags do propagate in CMake. I've updated my answer with the test results and would conclude that `add_compile_options()` is preferable over `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)` because the scope is - at least for me - easier to understand.

Answer (score 23):

The short answer is, that each sub-directory has it's own variable scope initialized with a copy of the current variable values at the time of the `add_subdirectory()` call.

For the long answer please see [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)

**Directory & Target Properties vs (Global) Variables**

There is a difference between how [`add_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_compile_options.html) and [`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html) are processed by CMake:

- Everything that you specify with `add_compile_options()` is appended to the [`COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_dir/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html#prop_dir:COMPILE_OPTIONS) directory property. Then "this property is used to initialize the `COMPILE_OPTIONS` target property when a target is created" with `add_library()` or `add_executable()`.

  And the current state of directory properties are used to initialize sub-directory properties when the parser gets to a `add_subdirectory()` call.
- The [`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html) is a global cached variable. You can extend/overwrite it by defining a local directory scoped variable (hiding the globally cached one).

  Those variable's context is copied into a sub-directories scope on `add_subdirectory()` (propagating to sub-directories).

  And CMake looks into its value at the *end* of the each `CMakeLists.txt` file and applies this to all targets in the same `CMakeLists.txt` (allowing late declarations, see also *Complete Formula* and *Test Code* below).
- So for CMake versions < 3.0 the equivalent to `add_compile_options()` was [`add_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_definitions.html). The functionality is still there, but it was strange to mix definitions with compile options. So `add_compile_options()` was invented.

**The complete Generator-Formula for Compiler Flags**

It's in CMake's code (see [`cmCommonTargetGenerator::GetFlags()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmCommonTargetGenerator.cxx#L297), [`cmLocalGenerator::AddCompileOptions()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmLocalGenerator.cxx#L1155) and [`cmLocalGenerator::AddLanguageFlags()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmLocalGenerator.cxx#L1816)).

This example shows a `DEBUG` build configuration library without exports, not taking into account the feature-based flags or something like `CMAKE_CXX_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_INCLUDES` or `CMAKE_QUOTE_INCLUDE_PATHS`:

```
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS       // as set at the end of target's CMakeLists.txt
+ CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG

+ Include Directories   // pefixed with CMAKE_INCLUDE_FLAG_CXX/CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_CXX

    (CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR) ? 
        + CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR + CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR
    + CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    + Target[INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES]
    + DependingTargets[INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES] 

+ Define Flags         // compiler flags given with add_definitions()
+ Target[COMPILE_FLAGS] // deprecated
    - Filtered by CMAKE_CXX_FLAG_REGEX
+ Target[COMPILE_OPTIONS]
+ DependingTargets[INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS]
```

**Test Code**

For a better understanding here is my code for testing the compiler options and the results I get:

*Note*: Normally I would use `add_definitions()` and `target_compile_definitions()` instead of `add_compile_options()` and `target_compile_options()` to set compiler definitions, but to demonstrate the propagating of compiler options I (mis-)used `-D` flags.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(CxxFlagsTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DCXX_FLAG")
add_compile_options("-DCOMPILE_OPTION")

add_subdirectory(lib)

file(WRITE main.cpp "int main() { return 0; }")
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main lib)

target_compile_options(main PRIVATE "-DMAIN_COMPILE_OPTION")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DLATE_CXX_FLAG")

get_target_property(_main_compile_options main COMPILE_OPTIONS)
message(STATUS "main COMPILE_OPTIONS: ${_main_compile_options}")
get_directory_property(_root_compile_options COMPILE_OPTIONS)
message(STATUS "root COMPILE_OPTIONS: ${_root_compile_options}")
message(STATUS "root CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

**lib/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DSUB_CXX_FLAG")
add_compile_options("-DSUB_COMPILE_OPTION")

file(WRITE lib.cpp "")
add_library(lib lib.cpp)

target_compile_options(lib PUBLIC "-DLIB_COMPILE_OPTION")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DLATE_SUB_CXX_FLAG")

get_target_property(_lib_compile_options lib COMPILE_OPTIONS)
message(STATUS "lib COMPILE_OPTIONS: ${_lib_compile_options}")
get_directory_property(_sub_compile_options COMPILE_OPTIONS)
message(STATUS "sub COMPILE_OPTIONS: ${_sub_compile_options}")
message(STATUS "sub CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

Would result in the following messages:

```
-- lib COMPILE_OPTIONS: -DCOMPILE_OPTION;-DSUB_COMPILE_OPTION;-DLIB_COMPILE_OPTION
-- sub COMPILE_OPTIONS: -DCOMPILE_OPTION;-DSUB_COMPILE_OPTION
-- sub CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:  ... -DCXX_FLAG -DSUB_CXX_FLAG -DLATE_SUB_CXX_FLAG
-- main COMPILE_OPTIONS: -DCOMPILE_OPTION;-DMAIN_COMPILE_OPTION
-- root COMPILE_OPTIONS: -DCOMPILE_OPTION
-- root CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:  ... -DCXX_FLAG -DLATE_CXX_FLAG
```

And the following pre-processor definitions being set:

***lib***

> ```
> CXX_FLAG
> SUB_CXX_FLAG
> LATE_SUB_CXX_FLAG
> COMPILE_OPTION
> SUB_COMPILE_OPTION
> LIB_COMPILE_OPTION
> ```

***main***

> ```
> CXX_FLAG
> LATE_CXX_FLAG
> COMPILE_OPTION
> MAIN_COMPILE_OPTION
> LIB_COMPILE_OPTION
> ```

The interesting parts here are the `LATE` CXX flags and the `LIB` compile option propagated the the linked library.

**References**

- [cmake - Global linker flag setting (for all targets in directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698580/cmake-global-linker-flag-setting-for-all-targets-in-directory)
- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)