# How to print a message exactly once per cmake invocation?

Tags: cmake

Wanting to cause a package foobar to print where it was found, when using

```
find_package(foobar CONFIG)
```

I am using

```
find_package_message(foobar
  "Found foobar: ${info} (version ${foobar_VERSION})"
  "[${info}][${foobar_VERSION}]"
)
```

The idea of using `find_package_message` is to only
print this message once.

However, I want to print it every time cmake is run from the start.
I only want to avoid duplicates during the same run of cmake.

`find_package_message` stores a variable in the cache (`FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_foobar`)
containing the value of the above third argument (`"[${info}][${foobar_VERSION}]"`) and
prints the message again when that variable doesn't exist or changed.

So, the result of running cmake a second time is that nothing is printed: `FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_foobar` already exists in the cache and didn't change.

How can I fix this to print a message once *every* new invocation of cmake?

Comment: Can't you use your own variable? `if(NOT foobar_my_variable_message_already_printed) set(foobar_my_variable_message_already_printed TRUE) message(..) endif()`?

Comment: That wouldn't be a global variable right? So the message would still be printed if -say- a subdirectory contains a project that also does a find_package(foobar).

Comment: Well, this seems to work: https://github.com/CarloWood/libcwd/blob/master/cmake/libcwd_rConfig.cmake#L5

Answer (score 0):

Function `find_package_message` is intended for print the message once until "details" are changed. For achieve **different semantic** - print message once per `cmake` invocation - there are a little sense to use this function but **implement your own** one.

For differentiate the first function invocation from further ones one may check whether GLOBAL **property** is defined:

```
function(print_message_once name message)
  # Name of the custom GLOBAL property to check
  set(pname PRINT_MESSAGE_ONCE_DUMMY_${name})
  get_property(prop_defined GLOBAL PROPERTY ${pname} DEFINED)
  if (NOT prop_defined)
    message(STATUS "${message}")
    # Define a property so next time it will exist
    define_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY ${pname} BRIEF_DOCS "${name}" FULL_DOCS "${name}")
  endif()
endfunction()
```

Note, this function is no longer requires `details` argument. It is very unlikely that during a single `cmake` invocation one will clear the cache after the first finding the package and performs second search with different parameters.

Alternatively, instead of property check, one may check existence of the **function**:

```
function(print_message_once name message)
  # Name of the custom function to check
  set(fname _check_first_dummy_${name})
  if (NOT COMMAND ${fname})
    message(STATUS "${message}")
    # Define a function so next time it will exist
    function(${fname})
    endfunction()
  endif()
endfunction()
```

Usage of function `print_message_once` (defined above using any of 2 ways) "compatible" with `find_package_message` is

```
if(NOT foobar_FIND_QUIETLY)
  print_message_once(foobar
    "Found foobar: ${info} (version ${foobar_VERSION})"
  )
endif()
```

If desired, checking for `XXX_FIND_QUIETLY` variable (which reflects QUIET option of `find_package()` call) could be incorporated into `print_message_once` function itself.