# How to disable warnings of gcc compiler both in header and source files?

Tags: gcc, cmake, warnings, suppress-warnings

How to disable warnings of GCC compiler both in header and source files?

In main CMakeLisits.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Weffc++ -std=c++11")

...

add_subdirectory(lib)
```

In lib CMakeLisits.txt:

```
set(lib_SOURCES

...)

include_directories(${lib_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${lib_BINARY_DIR}/include)
add_library(ilib STATIC ${ilib_EXTRA_CFLAGS} ${ilib_SOURCES})

...
..
```

I've tried add in lib CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(SYSTEM ${lib_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${lib_BINARY_DIR}/include)
```

and it helped with headers, but I still have warnings in `*.cpp` files

Then I tried

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-effc++")
```

in lib, CMakeLists.txt, and warnings in header appeared again

Don't understand what's happening

```
CMake version 2.8.12.2
gcc version 4.9.3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Why don't you fix the code so that there are no warnings?  What warnings appear?  What code triggers those warnings?  You really haven't provided enough information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Please provide a minmal example which shows your problem. So a small but complete cpp and CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: There could be many reasons why this could not work (for more details on how to modify CXX flags see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive)). Please provide a [mcve]. A more general solution for CMake projects: I like the [Cross platform warning suppression](https://github.com/ruslo/sugar/wiki/Cross-platform-warning-suppression) work from [@ruslo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2288008/ruslo).