# Cmake not applying compile option using add_compile_options

Tags: cmake, g++

im trying to use cmake with the following compile options using add_compile_options : `add_compile_options(-pipe -O2 -std=c++98 -W -Wall -pedantic)`

But it does not seem to be actually used during the compilation.

`make -n | grep pedantic` does not return anything

Just for information, my cmake command and what it returns :

```
cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" -DARCH:STRING=x86 -Bosef -H. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- cmake run for linux x86
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/davidlevy/WS/LC4/main/osef
```

What can I do to actually have the options applied?

PS : I noticed they were not applied because make does not output a single warning

EDIT : If instead I use

```
set (
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "
  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pipe -O2 -std=c++98 -W -Wall -pedantic"
)
```

Make does `/usr/bin/g++    ; -pipe -O2 -std=c++98 -W -Wall -pedantic -I ENDOFTHECOMMAND` I dont know where does this ; comes from

Comment: An example of what part do you need? And Verbose confirm what I thought, no compilation options are given to g++

Comment: A minimal example that we could copy to our systems and try out. You did not include CMake code, where the problem most probably is located, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`add_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) does append to the [`COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) directory property and is taken as default for all `COMPILE_OPTIONS` properties of targets coming *after* the `add_compile_options()` command.

In difference to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` which applies to all targets in the current `CMakeLists.txt`.

So make sure `add_compile_options()` command is *before* the `add_library()`/`add_executable` in question.

From `add_compile_options()` documentation:

> Adds options to the compiler command line for targets in the current directory and below that are added **after** this command is invoked.

**References**

- [Is Cmake set variable recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive)

Comment: That was it, thanks. I didnt understand what they meant with that sentence

Comment: This really helps me. Maybe we should use **before** (the bold) to highlight it.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was my mistake and I have now learned something new thanks to you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
set (
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "
  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pipe -O2 -std=c++98 -W -Wall -pedantic"
)
```

it should be

```
set(
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pipe -O2 -std=c++98 -W -Wall -pedantic"
)
```

Because the synthax you want to use is `set(variable value)`. In your case you set `CMAKE_CXXFLAGS` to a list of the second (empty string) and third argument (flags added by you).

Documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/set.html

Comment: This work indeed (it was a last try poorly executed before going home). But `add_compile_options` is a better way to add compiler option, so im accepting the other answer.

Comment: No, the third argument is not ignored by `set()`. When you pass three or more arguments to `set()`, you end up creating a _list_. That's what the `...` part of `<value>...` means in the CMake docs you linked to. CMake represents a list as a string with items separated by a semicolon, which is why the output in the second half of the original question contained a semicolon. All that said, the correct way to append to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is indeed as this answer recommends.

Comment: @CraigScott You are right, thanks for hint, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

CMake documentation is ridiculous, they removed
`Adds options to the compiler command line for targets in the current directory and below that are added after this command is invoked.` from `add_compile_options()` manual. Thanks for this hint Florian.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/command/add_compile_options.html