# Disable -Werror for one of CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I have the following CMake file:

```
project(MyLib)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "release")
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror")
set(ROOT_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${ROOT_DIR}/bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${ROOT_DIR}/bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
set(MAIN_LIBRARY_NAME "mylib")

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test_app)
add_subdirectory(test_app1) <--- I want to disable -Werror flag for CMakeLists.txt in this folder.
add_subdirectory(test_app2)
```

How to disable -Werror flag for one of subdirectories? In the each of sub directories I have CMakeLists.txt too.

Comment: All variables and directory properties are copied to the subdirectory's context at the moment you call `add_subdirectory()`. Either modify `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` before this call or use [`add_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) and modify [`COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) sub-directory property after this call.

Comment: @Florian Not exactly a duplicate I would say. The answer to this question is contained in that question, not in one of its answers.

Comment: @Antonio 
So I need to do like in example in this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/… ?

Comment: @Antonio Or I can add some compile options? As far I understand I can use add_compile_options() after add_subdirectory(test_app1) , or am I mistaken?

Comment: @VolodymyrHnatiuk You should put `add_compile_options` in the subdirectory CMakeLists.txt file, at the beginning. All its subsubdirectory will inherit the options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

All variables and directory properties are copied to the subdirectory's context at the moment you call `add_subdirectory()`. Either modify `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` before this call with something like

```
string(REPLACE " -Werror" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
add_subdirectory(test_app1) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Werror")
```

Or use the "old way" were compiler flags could be given with `add_definitions()` and removed with `remove_definitions()`

```
add_definitions(-std=c++11 -Wall -Werror)
...
remove_definitions(-Werror)
add_subdirectory(test_app1)
add_definitions(-Werror)
```

But you can - in contradiction to my first comment - change flags added `add_compile_options()` only on target level `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property and not for complete directories. When the target is created the property is copied as-is from the directory to the target and changing the directory property later won't automatically update the target's property.

If you have a newer CMake version that supports `SOURCE_DIR` target property you can alternatively go by some crazy generator expression:

```
add_compile_options(
    -std=c++11 
    -Wall 
    $<$<NOT:$<STREQUAL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:SOURCE_DIR>,${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test_app1>>:-Werror>
)
```

**Reference**

- [Is Cmake set variable recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CMake v3.24's new [`CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR` variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR.html), which initializes [the corresponding target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR.html), you can simply set the variable to `FALSE` in the CMakeLists.txt file of any subdirectories where you won't want warnings to be errors.

There are two nice things about using this variable:

- Cross-platform with less boilerplate: No more explicitly written generator expressions to use the right flag for each compiler.
- Allows user-override: Not all users will want to build with warnings as errors. This new feature comes with a [`--compile-no-warning-as-error`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-compile-no-warning-as-error) command-line flag that users can use to disable any effects of this variable/target-property when set by a dev in a CMakeLists.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

we have a project setup which configured `Werror` and `Wall` at the top level as compiler flags. What I ended up doing for a temporary test program which I wanted to skip `Werror` was:

```
add_executable(test_program ...)
target_compile_options(test_program PRIVATE -Wno-error)
```

that ended up generating a compile line like:

```
g++ ... -Wall -Werror -Wno-error test.cpp -o test
```

where the `-Wno-error` cancels out the `-Werror`, without affecting the `CXXFLAGS` for the rest of the project.