# How can I suppress warnings from an external library in a subdirectory?

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-warnings

I have an external library which I'm using in my package

```
- package/
  - include/
  - src/
  - external_library/
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - CMakeLists.txt
```

and currently in `package/CMakeLists.txt` I add the external library by

```
add_subdirectory(external_library library_name)
add_executable(my_executable src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_executable library_name)
```

and within `external_library/CMakeLists.txt` there is something like

```
add_library(library_name <files>)
```

I'd like to disable warnings from files in `external_library/` so I can change the error settings in `package/CMakeLists.txt` without seeing conflicts from the external library. I would like to avoid changing anything in `external_library/` if at all possible. How can that be done?

Comment: Related, (but not a dup of): [How to selectively enable or disable -Werror argument for entire (external project) directories in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73384774/11107541)

Answer (score 1):

You could manually add the `-w` flag for each external target, which disables all warnings on [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), Clang, and [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level) (or whatever flag for your compiler for a specific warning you want to disable), and rely on the fact that later flags will override previous flags for those compilers. Ex. To disable all warnings for the compilation of a target, you'd use `target_compile_options(foo PRIVATE -w)`.

If there are a lot of targets in the external project and you want to suppress warnings for all of them in a similar fashion, assuming you don't want to modify the external project's CMakeLists.txt files, you can save a copy of [the `COMPILE_OPTIONS` directory property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html), modify it, add the subdirectory, and then restore the old value. Ex.

```
# retrieve a copy of the current directory's `COMPILE_OPTIONS`
get_directory_property(old_dir_compile_options COMPILE_OPTIONS)

# modify the actual value of the current directory's `COMPILE_OPTIONS` (copy from above line remains unchanged). subdirectories inherit a copy of their parent's `COMPILE_OPTIONS` at the time the subdirectory is processed.
add_compile_options(-w)

# add you subdirectory (whichever way you do it)
# add_subdirectory(external ...)
# FetchContent_MakeAvailable(...)

# restore the current directory's old `COMPILE_OPTIONS`
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "${old_dir_compile_options}")
```

If the warnings are in the library's headers and they're happening when you include the headers, try marking the target as `SYSTEM` (which you can do with `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)` or higher by using [the `SYSTEM` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SYSTEM.html)). Pre-CMake 3.25, you can use a workaround in which you copy/move the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property to the `INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property ([related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64139281/11107541)). There may be other ramifications to doing this, but one of the side-effects of marking a target as `SYSTEM` is usually that the compiler will not emit warnings for them when `#include`d by something that has warning flags.

If you have `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)` or higher and the external library is header-only, you can consider a different solution. [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) and [`FetchContent_Declare`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_declare) come with a `SYSTEM` option that you can use, which causes all targets added in the corresponding subdirectory and under to have their include directories all treated as being `SYSTEM` (which will result in CMake generating a corresponding include flag for the compiler).

Comment: the external library only has one target (the add_library target) but many files come together when it calls add_library

Comment: Setting `add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)` in the beginning of the cmake, both the proposed strategies fail. Both meaning the `set_directory_properties` and `target_compile_options`

Comment: @MortenNissov https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253372/room-for-user-and-morten-nissov

Answer (score -1):

Use the `set_source_files_properties` to set the `COMPILE_FLAGS` to ignore warnings (`-w`) for all source files of your external library.

```
# package/CMakeLists.txt 

# Get the list of all sources of external_lib
file(GLOB EXTERNAL_LIBRARY_SOURCES external_library/*.cpp)

set_source_files_properties(
    ${EXTERNAL_LIBRARY_SOURCES}
    PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-w"
)

add_subdirectory(external_library library_name)
add_executable(my_executable src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_executable library_name)
```

Comment: isn't glob generally considered to be bad practice for modern cmake?

Comment: This is one way to get all the source files of the external library. Otherwise, you would have to list each source file of the external library that generates warnings individually. While GLOB is considered bad practice because it does not handle changes in the file system, in our case, as you have stated, the external library is unchanged, so it should not be affected.