# Different warning levels (though target_compile_options) for static library subproject in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
project(MyProject)
add_subdirectory(SomeLibrary)
add_executable(MyProject ${SRC_FILES})
target_compile_options(MyProject PRIVATE -Werror -Wall)
target_link_libraries(MyProject SomeLibrary)
```

Where `SomeLibrary` is a 3rd party library (linked as a git submodule) that will fail to build with `-Werror -Wall`

I want to build my project with `-Werror -Wall`, but disable `-Werror` for the subproject. How can I do this?

I saw [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182827/disable-werror-for-one-of-cmakelists-txt), but that covers the case where the flags are set directly through `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` - not `target_compile_options`.

Comment: Do the errors occur in the library's cpp files or in the header files you include from your project? BTW, consider raising an issue with the third party library. Compiling with `-Wall` isn't too much to ask for.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64064157/is-there-a-way-to-get-isystem-for-fetchcontent-targets) help? `-isystem` is a flag to ignore warnings from headers in specific locations (and more).

Comment: @Friedrich Oh, nice catch! I feel kind of silly for not realising, but the issue was actually in one of the imported headers. I guess there's no way around that then, except maybe disabling the specific warnings through compiler-specific "#pragma" directives (`#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored` etc.).
And yes, I'm planning to make a PR fixing these. Though, I know of one closed-source library we're using where that isn't really an alternative (a huge library containing *hundreds* of problematic headers). Not sure what's the best way to deal with that tbh.
Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @MyNiceDisplayName sometimes you're too close to see the issue. Happens to all of us. You should write a short answer, though. You will be able to accept your answer after 48 hours. Thanks.

Comment: @Friedrich Thanks! It's not the first time haha :) And yes, good idea! I'll do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get -isystem for FetchContent targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64064157/is-there-a-way-to-get-isystem-for-fetchcontent-targets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question (thanks to @Friedrich for pointing me in the right direction):

Turns out `target_compile_options` does after all work per-target, and I had simply misread the compilation output. The errors came from a header exposed by the 3rdparty library, which was included from my own project. So the third party library builds fine, since it is built without `-Werror`, but my main project (which is built with `_Werror`) fails.

I guess the only way to fix this is to either:

- Fix the problematic headers yourself (and notify maintainer / make PR).
- Use compiler-specific `#pragma` directives (`#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored` or `#pragma warning` on MSVC) to disable the specific warnings when including the problematic headers.