# How to clear all defines from cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have project where I need some specific preprocessor definitions. Nothing less nothing more. I tried various solutions:

```
set(DEFINES MY_DEFINE)
target_compile_definitions(my_target PRIVATE ${DEFINES})
```

and

```
set(DEFINES -DMY_DEFINE)
add_definitions(${DEFINES})
```

even

```
set(DEFINES MY_DEFINE)
set_property(TARGET my_target PROPERTY CACHE COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ${DEFINES})
```

Every time cmake still injects some other defines:

```
WIN32
_WINDOWS
CMAKE_INTDIR="$(CONFIG)"
```

My target is static library and project generator is Visual Studio 2015 if it might influence anything. How can I get cmake to set only my defines?

Comment: Defines like `WIN32` or `_WINDOWS` are needed for standard libraries. Without them, even simple `printf()` may to not work.

Comment: I understand that they might be needed, but my project requires that they are not set.

Comment: Normally, platform-dependenet compiler flags come with *CMAKE_C_FLAGS*/ *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS*. You may try to set these variable to empty value.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since those are platform specific defines in CMake, you can only remove them "globally" for your current `CMakeList.txt` scope (not for an idividual taret) with something like:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "(-D|/D)[^ ]* " "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

**Reference**

- [Is Cmake set variable recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that was my problem. I've cleared all CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in cmake file above, so I've excepted that in all files below that file flags will be cleared.

Comment: :( <-- frowny-face

Answer (score 0):

In CMake, you can use [remove_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/remove_definitions.html) for any definitions added via add_definitions. I'm not sure if that will work here, though, because cmake may not be adding them via add_definitions.

You could also potentially [#undef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4w8783.aspx) those definitions at the very top of your C++ files. This is a little bit dirtier, but it might work.

Comment: I thought about remove_definitions, but in that case I need to enter defines to remove directly inside my cmake file and I'm looking for cleaner (and more important - more generic) solution.