# Target Specific files with CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-warnings

I am attempting to use the much stricter `-Weffc++` compiler flag for a project.  The issue that I'm having is that the project uses a bunch of open-source libraries.  These libraries in no way adhere to the stricter requirements, and I have no intention of modifying them to comply.

Is there a way to target a specific set of files with a compilation option using CMake?

Furthermore, the compilation is conditional on what is compiling the program.  The program can either be compiled as an executable, or it can be compiled as a library so that it can be used by the automated unit test fixtures employed.

Is there a way to target a specific subdirectory added with the `add_subdirectory` CMake command, with specific compile flags?

Thank you!

Comment: According to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33834879/3440745), variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is actually applied to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify all relevant targets, I recommend using `target_compile_options`, `target_compile_definitions` and or/ `target_link_options` to achieve your goals. You could introduce a cmake function, if the same compiler/linker options are required for multiple targets.

```
target_compile_options(my_target PRIVATE -Weffc++)
```

If you want to target a subdirectory, you should be able to use `add_compile_options`/`add_compile_definitions`/`add_link_options` in a new scope using a function to restruct the scope for the settings. Note that you only need a function, if the options must not apply to every target added in the same `CMakeLists.txt` file after adding the subdirectory and to targets created in subdirectories added from the `CMakeLists.txt` file after adding the subdirectory. Using a function anyways doesn't "hurt" though and may even reduce the number of things you need to consider for future edits.

```
function(add_subdir_with_flags DIR)
    add_compile_options(-Weffc++)
    add_subdirectory(${DIR} ${ARGN}) # ARGN used to allow specifying the build dir for the subdir
endfunction()

...

add_subdir_with_flags(subdir1)
add_subdir_with_flags(subdir2 builddir2)
```

Note: If you want to go down to the source file level, you could do so by adding compile options on a per-file basis, but you should only use this option, if not all source files of a target should be compiled with these options.

```
# apply options only to foo.cpp and bar.cpp
set_source_files_properties(foo.cpp bar.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS -Weffc++)
```