# Why my Cmake already choose clang (-x c++) instead of clang++ to compile the codes?

Tags: cmake, clang

I have following setting in my Toolchain.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)

set(cross_triple "x86_64-linux-gnu")
set(clang_5.0 "/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts")
set(clang_link_flags "-lstdc++")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${clang_5.0}/bin/clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${clang_5.0}/bin/clang++)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wno-c++11-narrowing -v")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${clang_link_flags}")
```

And, my clang compiler folder as belows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1024 1024 15774563 May 11 21:06 sancov
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1024 1024  3925178 May 11 21:06 llvm-symbolizer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1024 1024 16048083 May 11 21:06 llvm-ar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1024 1024 63993992 May 11 21:06 lld
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1024 1024 82308936 May 11 21:06 clang
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1024 1024        3 May 18 01:11 ld.lld -> lld
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1024 1024        5 May 18 01:11 clang-cl -> clang
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1024 1024        5 May 18 01:11 clang++ -> clang
```

Everything looks fine for me. But, when I use Cmake then make to compile my project, for all the .cpp .c files, Cmake choose to use clang instead of clang++ to compile the source codes, like:

"/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang" -cc1 -x c++ xxx.cpp -o xxx.cpp.o

For some reason, the "-lstdc++" flags won't take affect in the linker, which cause some issues.

My questions:

1. why cmake choose to use "clang -x c++", instead of directly using clang++? Anything missing here? How to let cmake choose clang++?
2. define "-lstdc++" in CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS look like does not take affect. Can you tell what can be the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: The second question is easily searched. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698580/cmake-global-linker-flag-setting-for-all-targets-in-directory.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem that CMake uses `clang -x c++`, it's just telling the clang front end to compile the source as C++ anyway. Rather than explicitly specifying the `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` flags, you probably should instead be looking to use the following in your project's CMakeLists.txt file if it needs C++11 support:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

You can find a detailed discussion of how to set up for C++11 and later [here](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/).

As for the remaining compiler and linker flags you are trying to set, you might want to check out [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_INIT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_INIT.html) and [`CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT.html) as alternative ways of setting those. They are intended for use in toolchain files to do the sort of thing you are trying to do (but if you use the C++11 method above, you won't need to change the linker flags at all).