# How to enable a specific c++ warning in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, warnings

my project warnlevel is /w3. 
I want to enable as single warning from warnlevel 4. 
Such as "C4296 'operator' : expression is always false"

How can I do this in cxx flags of my CMake file?

Comment: In what sense is your Visual Studio project integrated with CMake? I am not aware that they fit together out of the box. http://stackoverflow.com/q/395169/560648 http://stackoverflow.com/q/4151908/560648

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx
*"For example, /w14326 causes C4326 to be generated as a level 1 warning."*

Answer (score 2):

Just add to your main `CMakeLists.txt` (CMake version >= 2.8.12) generally

```
add_compile_options("$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/w34296>")
```

or (thanks [@tambre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2176813/tambre) for the hint) just to a specific target

```
target_add_compile_options(MyTarget "$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/w34296>")
```

The shwon [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#logical-expressions) will add warning C4296 to warning level 3 for `MSVC` compilers (for the VC warning options see [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx) provided by [@Richard Critten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3370124/richard-critten))

Some more possibilities for setting compile option with CMake in Visual Studio projects can be found in my answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621092/cmake-setting-compile-flags-for-libraries).

Answer (score -2):

This code works for me.

```
#enable compiler warning C4296 in warnlevel 3
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /w34296 ")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /w34296 ")
```

Comment: This is quite terrible, as it sets the option for *all* other compilation units also in your project. Those variables should no longer be used in modern CMake.