# CMake CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS enabled optimization unexpectly

Tags: cmake

In one of my CMakeLists.txt, I have the follow instructions:

```
IF ( MSVC )
    SET ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MDd" )
)
```

After the MSVC 10.0 solution is created, the optimization (/O2)  is unexpectedly enabled by the code above. I'm sure I didn't enable it somewhere else.

Why is that?

Comment: What's the type of the build? I suppose, `Release`. You may try to explicitly select `Debug`: `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`. In this case CMake provides suitable flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code in your question you are hiding the default parameters - including the optimization level - that CMake does apply.

Please try appending your options with

```
SET ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MDd" )
```

or with the use of [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) and [`add_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_compile_options.html):

```
add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/MDd>")
```

But you may not need this particular option, because `/MDd` is already part of CMake's default MSVC debug flag's setting.

**Background**

If you look at CMake's [`Windows-MSVC.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Windows-MSVC.cmake#L300) you'll see the following initialization settings:

```
set(CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "/D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od ${_RTC1}")
```

Without changing any flags in your `CMakeLists.txt` you will see in your `CMakeCache.txt`:

```
//Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
```

With your code you are hiding this cached variable and you will end up with just `/MDd`.

**References**

- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)
- [cmake - Global linker flag setting (for all targets in directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698580/cmake-global-linker-flag-setting-for-all-targets-in-directory)
- [CMAKE - setting compile flags for libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621092/cmake-setting-compile-flags-for-libraries)
- [Change default value of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG and friends in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732209/change-default-value-of-cmake-cxx-flags-debug-and-friends-in-cmake)

Comment: That's it ! Great answer BTW.

Comment: @ShaoboZi You are welcome. Just wanted to share another link I found useful when struggling with CMake: [A list of common CMake antipatterns](http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2013/03/26/a-list-of-common-cmake-antipatterns/).